# iOS 12 web eventListener deviceorientation

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I try to implement javascript event listener for 'deviceorientation'.

Code:

```
if (!window.DeviceOrientationEvent) {
    alert("Sorry, but Device Orientation is not suported!");
} else {
    alert("YES!!!");
    window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', orientationHandler);
}

function orientationHandler(e) {
    alert(e.gamma); //<--Never show
  if(e.beta < 0){
    right = true;
    left = false;
  } else if(e.beta > 0){
    right = false;
    left = true;
  } else {
    right = false;
    left = false;
  }
}
```

On Desktop Chrome result is alert "Sorry, but Device Orientation is not supported!". When I test in Safari(iPhone 7, iOS 12.3.1) result is alert "YES!!!", but after that nothing happen.

I have also implement touch listener like:

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", touchStartHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("touchend", touchEndHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("touchmove", touchMoveHandler, false);

function touchStartHandler(e) {
    mouseOrTouchDown = true;
    touchMoveHandler(e);
}

function touchEndHandler(e) {
    mouseOrTouchDown = false;
        right = false;
        left = false;
}

function touchMoveHandler(e) {
    if(mouseOrTouchDown){
    mouseOrTouchLastX = e.touches[0].clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    if (mouseOrTouchLastX > paddleX){
        right = true;
        left = false;
    } else if(mouseOrTouchLastX < paddleX){
        right = false;
        left = true;
    } else {
        right = false;
        left = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And it works perfect.

I host my project with XAMPP.

I also try [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-device-orientation-api--cms-21067) tutorial and online demo [here](https://www.audero.it/demo/device-orientation-api-demo.html). When I open online demo it works on my phone, but when I get code from tutorial(or from page with demo) it doesn't move again like in my code. I think that maybe problem is from XAMPP(I don't know) or something similar because there is no other difference.

Edit: I tried and Note.js http-server but result is same.

I tried to debug browser log(using [this](https://washamdev.com/debug-a-website-in-ios-safari-on-windows/) tutorial), but have problem with see device in Chrome DevTools(that is another thing) on Windows 8.1.

I can see what I miss. Maybe there is some trust flag or some setting that block this eventListener